# Windows Server 2022 NAS/SAN

Tags: windows, network-attached-storage, sas, fiber

I have a Windows Server 2022 server intended to be used as storage server.

In the server are two LSI 1068 HBA cards. First plan was MPIO, but is not working.
The two LSI controllers have two SAS cables to an HP D2700 Bay with two controllers. (second cable doing nothing at the moment). There are also two QLogic HBA SPF+ cards installed.

The plan is to make an SPF fiber connection to two servers with two SPF HBA cards to access the storage pool direct. That means that the HBA SPF controllers in the servers must be a "client" and the Qlogic HBA SPF cards in this server must be a "Server".

I can not find documentation how to setup this "storage server" to act as a NAS for the 2 other servers.

In my MPIO list the two Qlogic cards are seen as MPIO devices. But the LSI are not in the list.

I can cancel the D2700 if I find a other solution where I can store the 25 HP disks. The caddy is not compatible with the new servers. They only fit in HP Gen7 and older or an HP drive bay like the D2700.

I understand that if you connect to HBA controllers they can not talk "ethernet". So it will not be a "network connection". What it will be then? An iSCSI device?

Any advice?

Update:

After all good advise. I am going to delete Windows and install linux, than I can install the "target-mode".
Thank you for all good advise.

Comment: with the unknown server which has usually has a known vendor where you can request documents, documentation and may have to open a support case on the unknown vendor

Comment: Its a HP server and they tell me that the hardware supports it. That it is a Microsoft windows question. I dont have good experience with calling Microsoft for support and getting the right answers.

Comment: but they can usually tell you about the right setting to choose. But I would suggest that you contract a Person which solve this business case for you

Answer (score 4):

You’ll need something called “Target mode” server software. They exist for iSCSI (lots), Fibre Channel (less), and SAS (few). Unfortunately for you no SAS target mode stack exists for Windows OS. The only workaround I can offer is to enable Hyper-V role, spawn a Linux VM, PCI-pass-thru your HBAs and try playing with Linux Target mode software. Here’s a set of links below (with some comments):

(SCST got banned as a default target for Linux, drivers for HBAs are in beta, and… They’re Marvel, not Qlogic)

https://scst.sourceforge.net/target_mvsas.html

(SCST, LSI drivers, you’ll need to tinker around…)

https://github.com/exactassembly/meta-xa-stm

(ATTO has some target-mode products, like Tape Redirector, you might want to talk to them as well…)

https://www.atto.com/landing/target-mode-sdk

Good luck! You’ll need a lot of it for your quite interesting project.